# FoundationCSS Side affects if not including row

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Using FoundationCSS, if I use the basic grid system by defining a row and then columns, I get a grid that is 1000px wide on desktop.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

However, if I do the same thing, but omit the "row", I get a full width layout.

```
<div class="small-12 columns">
  ...
</div>
```

Are there any side affects I should be aware of by omitting the "row"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [zurb foundation is it possible to have full row width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751391/zurb-foundation-is-it-possible-to-have-full-row-width)

Comment: it seems that what is on either side of `<row>` is cut off by media queries, so you can try it but I would expect smaller screens to chop some  content off.

Answer (score 1):

The safest thing I found was to add a new class to make the container full-width:

```
.full-width {
   width: 100%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   max-width: initial;
}
```

And use it in the html:

```
<body>
  <div class="row full-width">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
      ....
    </div>
    <div class="row"
      <div class="small-6 columns>...</div>
      <div class="small-6 columns>...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```